# How to chain sed append commands?

Tags: sed

I wanted to apply changes to config file with SED command, it requires inserting some lines in a few places after starting tags.

However, when I've tried:

```
sed '/\[httpd/\]/a secure_rewrites = false; /\[couchdb/\]/adelayed_commits = false' local.ini
```

I've found out, that after [httpd] a line was appended:

> secure_rewrites = false; [couchdb]/a delayed_commits=false

which is obviously not what I've intended.

Is it possible to chain append commands?

Comment: You have extra slashes in the sed patterns (at the end of `httpd/` and `couchdb/`). I suppose they're not really there, since at least gnu sed would error on them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU `sed` (BSD `sed` will not add newlines after the added text, unless you include a literal newline in the string that is added):

```
sed -e '/\[httpd\]/a\'   -e 'secure_rewrites = false;' \
    -e '/\[couchdb\]/a\' -e 'delayed_commits = false;' local.ini
```

If the file contains

```
[httpd]
[couchdb]
```

initially, then the above `sed` command will produce

```
[httpd]
secure_rewrites = false;
[couchdb]
delayed_commits = false;
```

Also note that the `a` command for appending text is supposed to be written `a\` followed by the text appended.  GNU `sed` is forgiving about omitting the `\`.

---

As a `sed` script (works in any `sed`):

```
/\[httpd\]/a\
secure_rewrites = false;
/\[couchdb\]/a\
delayed_commits = false;
```

This could be use on the command line as a literal single quoted `sed` script string (a newline has to come after the last line), or stored separately and fed into `sed` using

```
$ sed -f script.sed local.ini
```

With `#!/usr/bin/sed -f`, as the first line (assuming the path to `sed` is correct), the script could even be run directly:

```
$ ./script.sed local.ini
```

Answer (score 3):

As GNU `sed` **`a text`** subcommand operates a text to add which is read until the end of the line, you may apply the following trick (imitating a linebreak):

```
sed '/\[httpd\]/a secure_rewrites = false;
/\[couchdb\]/adelayed_commits = false' local.ini
```

Sample output:

```
...
[httpd]
secure_rewrites = false;
...
[couchdb]
delayed_commits = false
```